# Netty : URI Based Websocket networking

Tags: java, netty

I'm on new on Netty framework.

I wrote some chatting module using it.

This is my simple chat server project snippet of `ChannelInitializer`.

```
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

        p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec())
                .addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536))
                .addLast( new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/chat"))
                .addLast(new WsUserAcceptHandler())
...
```

This is very simple. Each handler check messages from `/chat`, and decides that handle or not.

But now, I want to give unique URI on each handler.
Would you give me some tips?

Comment: What do you mean by "give unique URI on each handler"?

Comment: Umm... sorry about not good on English.
For example,  when I requested `/chat/join/1` then `WsUserAcceptHandler`  handles this request, and `/chat/message/1` then `WsMessagingHandler` handles this. But why I wondering this,  `new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/chat")` specifies some URI, I think It means only upgrades to websocket connection to some URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question later, [Netty: How to use query string with websocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895443/netty-how-to-use-query-string-with-websocket/38951020#38951020)

This code help to support multiple URI on netty.